# Is it possible to animate a constraint in iOS 7 custom transition

Tags: ios7, autolayout, custom-transition

All I can seem to find in examples are using transforms or are modifying frames. Have I missed something obvious? Currently the other animations (fades) are all working fine, however the constraint stays locked in position.

A quick code snippet:

```
[[customViewController view] layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{

    [[customViewController constraintToAnimate] setConstant:1024];
    [[customViewController view] layoutIfNeeded];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}];
```

Comment: Guess I should take that as a no..

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Any help or discovery?

Comment: I haven't found a way yet - I'm falling back to frame animation for now

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to use autolayout in my UI. Can I mix autolayout and at the same time use frames in transitions? Thanks.

Comment: Yes frames work fine in the transitions - though you do have a lot more code to write.

Comment: No, you should not be updating frames manually if you are using auto layout, since the layout engine will change the frames out from under you to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: Not during a custom transition. In normal code you're absolutely right and shouldn't touch the frames when using autolayout, however, in this case autolayout isn't working in a custom transition. Unless you can help us all out and provide some sample that proves otherwise?

Comment: Are you sure the value of the constant is different than 1024 before the animation block is executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the `[[customViewController view] superview]`

Comment: Not sure if this was the answer back in the day but it was the most helpful. Testing in iOS 9 seems to just allow constraint manipulation directly without having to worry about the superview.